# Does adding a non clustered index to foreign key speed up the join?

Tags: sql-server, index

I have 2 large tables.

Sample query:

```
SELECT USERNAME,S.ProductName,S.Amt,S.Date
FROM USERS U
JOIN SALES S
ON U.ID=S.UID
```

Presently the Users.ID and Sales.ID are clustered indexes.

So as to speed up the JOIN, will it help if I add a non-clustered index on Sales.UID? And add the following columns as included column: ProductName, Amt and Date?

Comment: It really [depends](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/11/adventures-in-foreign-keys-how-should-i-index-these-things/), so [try](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/11/t-sql-queries/benefits-indexing-foreign-keys) and see what happens. Also consider what other things happen to your tables.

Answer (score 4):

Even if it doesn't speed up *that* query an index on the foreign key will help if you ever delete a user, or select a the sales of a single user.  eg

```
SELECT USERNAME,S.ProductName,S.Amt,S.Date
FROM USERS U
JOIN SALES S
ON U.ID=S.UID
WHERE U.ID = @user
```

So indexing foreign key columns is generally recommended.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to know for sure is to try it. There are many factors involved, so all we can do is speculate.

It is possible that the index can help.

SQL Server can scan the Users table and for each row do a look for matching rows in the Sales table. I.e., a loop join having the Users table as the outer table. Having an index on the join column for the Sales table makes this lookup being able to use that index (instead of doing a table scan in the Sales table for each ro in the Users table). Also, since that index covers the query, there is no need to go from the leaf level of that index to the actual data row.

Or SQL Server could instead scan the Sales table, and for each row look for matching rows in the Users table. Still a loop join, but now the Sales table is instead the outer table. The benefit here wouldn't be so high, the only gain is having a smaller  set of data to scan, since it can scan the leaf level of that index on the Sales table instead of the actual data.

Or, SQL Server can do a merge join. The data is already sorted on the join column for the Users table, having a clustered index on the ID column. And by creating that index on the Sales table, SQL Server now also have a covering index sorted on the join column for the Sales table. I.e., the prerequisites for a merge join are met.

Of course we don't know which strategy it would take. It might even not use that index and do a hash join instead.

The optimizer is (mostly) cost based. It will cost estimate the alternatives (as per given above) and decide on whichever it believe is the cheapest.

Answer (score -1):

For that specific query it will have to scan *both* tables and either sort (probably spooling to disk if the tables are large) or hash-match to perform the join.

With an index on Sales.UID it will likely scan users and be able to join using sales more efficiently because the joining field is pre-sorted by the index. Including the other fields will save needing to perform further lookups on the clustering key to find the extra data. So it will *probably* help a fair bit, but you'll only know for sure by testing (depending on the number of rows present, and the pattern of data in the affected columns, it may still choose to scan & hash-match, or something else).

If you are likely to search by date rather than listing *all* sales, then an index with Sales.Date as the first covered column might be more helpful. Of course if both sorts of queries are common both indexes may be a good idea, though as you add more indexes (particularly when INCLUDEing extra columns) keep an eye on how much storage space is being taken, and if they slow insert/update activity enough to be an issue.